# Problems decoding an image file copied using Okio and ContentResolver.openInputStream()

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory, okio

I have the following setup: a gallery image gets selected using `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent and then in `onActivityResult()` I get an Intent with an Uri. Next I try to do the following:

```
Source source = Okio.source(getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData()));
BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(new File(outPath)));
long bytesWritten = sink.writeAll(source);
```

Here `outPath` is a valid path to existing 0-length file created in advance.

The copy operation completes without an error, `bytesWritten` return an actual bytes, which are same as the source file's size.

But when I do this afterwards:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(outFile);
```

It returns `null` and produces a `skia: decoder returned false` log message. Which usually means that file's format is wrong.

Why is that? I also tried to do the same thing without using `Okio` (just writing a lot of ugly code which copies InputStream to OutputStream) and results were the same. Any hints?

Note, that the following works, but it has the downside that I have to additionally decode Bitmap. While I'd rather just copy InputStream to a file.

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData()));
outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 92, outStream);
```

Comment: and what is the content of `outFile` ?

Comment: @pskink hmm, just checked and it indeed looks strange, notice the unfinished strip at the bottom... So I guess for some reason it didn't flush() or what? http://i.imgur.com/8o4sQGO.jpg

Comment: yes, most likely flush() / close() problem

Comment: Oh, Indeed it seems like I didn't call close! Can you please submit this as an answer, I will accept.